Timestamp at node level in Extent Report 5.1.2
I have created extent report in my selenium with java code. I am unable to understand timestamp generated at each node level at right side between attachment icon & pass status. What does it stand for?
what does timestamp stand for?
Extent Report Version: 5.1.2
